# Serial Port Communication Protocol

Tags: serial-communication, digital

In serial communication with devices such as a digital Multimeter (ex. BK Precision 2831E), why do I need to send a query command once but read the output twice? For instance, I sent a query command for  the voltage measured, and received an echo but no value of voltage.
I then sent the query command twice which returned the echo and the measured voltage. In essence, to read out the voltage measured, I had to send the same query command in succession twice.
I do not understand this concept. Can anyone kindly help me out with this reasoning.

I have attached a sample code here below:

```
def readoutmm(portnumber_multimeter):
    import serial
    import time
    ser2 = serial.Serial(
    port="com"+str(portnumber_multimeter),
    baudrate=9600,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,  
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    )
    ser2.write(b'fetc?\n') # Query command
    voltage= ser2.readline() # Returns echo
    voltage=ser2.readline() # Returns measured voltage
    voltage=float(voltage)
    ser2.close()
    packet=[voltage]
    return packet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite common with devices based on RS232/RS485 protocols.

From the [manual of the machine you mentioned](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1314008/Bk-Precision-2831e.html?page=42#manual), I quote:

> The character received by the multimeter will be sent back to the controller again. The controller will
> not send the next character until the last returned character is received correctly from the meter. If
> the controller fails to receive the character sent back from the meter, the possible reasons are listed
> as follows:
>
> - The serial interface is not connected correctly.
> - Check if the same baud rate is selected for both the meter and the controller.
> - When the meter is busy with executing a bus command, it will not accept any character from
>   the serial interface at the same time. So the character sent by controller will be ignored.
>
> In order
> to make sure the whole command is sent and received correctly, the character without a return character should be sent again by the controller.

On a lot of devices this is actually a setting which you can turn on and off.

Now, as for your question:

> why do I need to send a query command once but read the output twice?

You are supposed to read every character back before sending a new one to validate if the character was received correctly. But in your code are actually sending all the character before reading a single one of them.

In scenario's where you have a reliable connection, you method will work as well, but as a consequence you'll need to read twice; once to validate if the command was received and the second time to retrieve the actual data.

Do keep in mind that read buffers might be limited to a certain amount. If you are experiencing unexpected behavior while querying large amount of data and sending a lot of commands, it might be due to the fact these buffers are full.

Comment: That makes this concept very clear. Thanks for the help and taking out time

Comment: To further clarify on this topic of discussion:
As you said, the read buffers might have limited storage, is there any way I can exception handle this to prevent my algorithm from crashing? Or any other solution?

Comment: As long as the buffers are read, you're good and a crash is unlikely. You can always uses pythons [try-except](https://www.codingem.com/try-catch-in-python/) construction.But this will stop execution of the algorithm. I would approach this in a pragmatic way: the amount of data returned will be within specified boundaries. As long as you send the command and directly read the result, it should not cause any issues.